# How to style a markdown fenced code block using css?

Tags: css, markdown

In a markdown fenced code block I would like to style **only one** block with the following css:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffd4d4 25%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 50%, #ffd4d4 50%, #ffd4d4 75%, #ffffff 75%, #ffffff 100%);
background-size: 11.31px 11.31px;
```

Is such a thing possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the specific block you wish to style, then do:

```css
.added-class {
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffd4d4 25%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 50%, #ffd4d4 50%, #ffd4d4 75%, #ffffff 75%, #ffffff 100%);
background-size: 11.31px 11.31px;
}
```

If you can modify only the markdown file, take a look at [this](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#heading-ids). Then you do the same as above except with an id.

Maybe a little more details on your code could help us to understand what exactly is the problem.